# Use recursive MATLAB function or optimization?

Tags: matlab, recursion, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to decide the most efficient, yet most precise approach to calculate a value called `R` which can only take a value between `0` and `1`. Right now I have the below function used in the below script, but I feel like I am doing this in a non-optimal way. Currently I get an answer and have to feed that answer (again) as the initial "guess" in order to get the (next) most optimal answer. Could I build a better recursion for this or perhaps use one of Matlab's solvers? Thanks!

The function:

```
function f = Rfind(p,u,R)
    f = p .* (R.^u);
end
```

The script:

```
R = 0.999995753651217; % initial guess
matches = false;
while ~matches && R < 1
    R = R + 0.0000000000000000001; % increment R for next guess
    Jtotal = sum(Rfind(p,u,R)); % find R
    if abs(Jtotal - R)*10000000000 < 5 % check precision of result
        matches = true; % if R matches R fed to function, successful
    end
end
Jtotal
```

What I'm trying to identify:

Find a value of `R` equal to the sum of array `p` times `R` to the power of array `u`. Array `p` and array `u` both have the same number of elements, i.e. 12 rows in 1 column each. My function calculates `R` for each `p` and `u` row and then increments its guess to find the next closest match. It stops once the precision limit has been met or the input `R` and output total are identical.

Example Data:

**Array `p`**

```
0.00000693
0.00000231
0.00001386
0.00000924
0.00041360
0.00461657
0.03085337
0.01595235
0.09614154
0.06832660
0.11103563
0.67262800
```

**Array `u`**

```
50000
500
50
25
10
7.5
5
3.5
2.5
1.25
1
0
```

**Important**: I need the best precision for this but I don't want it taking 10 minutes like it has with extensions of the above.

Comment: It would help if you expressed what you're trying to do mathematically too.

Comment: Note that you can calculate `Jtotal` faster using `sum(Rfind(p, u, R))` if you use elementwise operators in `Rfind`, i.e. `.^` and `.*`.

Comment: Can you also provide the values for `u` and `p`? Or an example for them if they may change.

Comment: I tried your elementwise suggestion and it did help with the speed (thanks). I just wish the script would run faster for the precision I need. So far the best answer has been 0.999995753651216 for the above dataset. The dataset does change which is why I need speed

Comment: Make your function anonymous, it should also save some time. Just type this before your `while` loop: `Rfind = @(p,u,R) p .* (R.^u);` P.S. you have a typo when calling the function in the loop (`Rfind2`).

Comment: Is the point of the whole thing to determine R experimentally? Because from the setup it looks like it could be possible to solve this analytically or at least with some sort of regression.

Comment: What toolkits do you have?  A binary search should work a lot faster, gradient-based search (e.g. Newton's method) faster yet).

Comment: Might I suggest graphing `abs(Jtotal - R)` vs `R` to help visualize the search space?  (Edit your question to add a link to the plot, one of us can then place the image inline)

Comment: I have most of the toolkits, including optimization. I would be open to implementing Newton's method but I am unfamiliar with it. I am unaware of an analytical solution.

Comment: I think you can use `Jerror = @(R) (R - sum(p .* (R.^u))); lsqnonlin(Jerror, Rguess, 0, 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`fminbnd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminbnd.html) for this:

```
% first assign p and u
% define the function that you want to minimize:
Rfind = @(R) abs(sum(p.*(R.^u)) - R)
% set the tolerance to maximum:
options = optimset('TolX',eps); 
% find the value between 0 to 1 that minimize the function Rfind:
[R, err] = fminbnd(Rfind,0,1,options)
```

and get (in a fraction of a second):

```
R =
   0.999995761369809
err =
     9.196743366857163e-11
```

Comment: You're missing an absolute value -- some optimization functions like `lsqnonlin` find minimum magnitude, but `fminbnd` appears to seek negative values.  Maybe the curve doesn't ever cross zero, in which case it doesn't matter.

Comment: Well, your `fval` output shows that it did go negative.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks for that catch. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Looks like a win, error is better than 1/5 what the code in the question allows.

Comment: I like that this answer doesn't require an initial guess for `R`. The error I get with `abs(R-Jtotal)*100000000000` is roughly 25, which is higher than the 0.43 with my "best solution"; however, this runs much faster and more efficiently. Thank you!